# Python: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'int'

Tags: python, loops, time-series, numpy-ndarray

**Code description:**
I am trying to calculate various rolling metrics on financial time series data. I am using a looped approach as I would like to simulate data coming in from an API.

My original code was using a simple itertuples loop which passed values to NumPy arrays for the rolling calculations. However, I would like to speed up the calculations with Numba. As such, I need to iterate through the data using NumPy within a function.

**I am getting the following error when trying to iterate through the Numpy array.**

```
PyDev console: starting.
Python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020, 17:10:11) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
runfile('F:/Python/Directories/Directed Reading/Data Handling 0.1 JIT.py', wdir='F:/Python/Directories/Directed Reading')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "F:/Python/Directories/Directed Reading/Data Handling 0.1 JIT.py", line 92, in <module>
    Results = RunBacktest(Gran, Period, ZMinMax, upperbound, lowerbound, UpperExit, LowerExit, Data)
  File "F:/Python/Directories/Directed Reading/Data Handling 0.1 JIT.py", line 60, in RunBacktest
    if bid > 0:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'int'
```

**The code is as follows:**

```
Data = "F:/Market Data/2020.3.15 FXAUDCAD-TICK-NoSession.h5"
df = pd.read_hdf(Data)
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DateTime']))
df = df.drop(columns=['DateTime'])
df = df.resample(Gran).mean()

t0 = time.time()
Array = df['Bid'].to_numpy()

def RunBacktest(Gran, Period, ZMinMax, upperbound, lowerbound, UpperExit, LowerExit, Array):

    # Arrays for storing "data feed"
    live_dtime_arr = np.array([])
    live_arr = np.array([])
    live_ma = np.array([])
    live_s_dev = np.array([])
    live_z_score = np.array([])
    live_buy_sig = np.array([])
    live_sell_sig = np.array([])

    count = 0
    sell_count = 0
    buy_count = 0

    # Loop through rows
    for i in np.nditer(Array):

        count += 1
        bid = i      #< this line is throwing the error

        #I did this to filter Nan data points
        if bid > 0:
            if count > Period:
                ma = live_arr[-Period:].mean()
                s_dev = live_arr[-Period:].std()
                z_score = (bid - ma) / s_dev
            else:
                ma = np.nan
                s_dev = np.nan
                z_score = np.nan

            if z_score > upperbound:
                sell_sig = bid
                sell_count += 1
            elif z_score < lowerbound:
                buy_sig = bid
                buy_count += 1
            else:
                signal_filter = 0
                sell_sig = np.nan
                buy_sig = np.nan

            live_arr = np.append(live_arr, [bid], axis=0)
            live_ma = np.append(live_ma, [bid], axis=0)
            live_s_dev = np.append(live_s_dev, [s_dev], axis=0)
            live_z_score = np.append(live_z_score, [z_score], axis=0)
            live_buy_sig = np.append(live_buy_sig, [buy_sig], axis=0)
            live_sell_sig = np.append(live_sell_sig, [sell_sig], axis=0)


        return live_arr

Results = RunBacktest(Gran, Period, ZMinMax, upperbound, lowerbound, UpperExit, LowerExit, Data)
print(Results)
```

**Sample Data:** (From df)

Note: There are some nan values in the 'Bid' column of the Pandas data frame

```
DateTime                 Bid                                              
2006-01-03 00:01:07.588  0.85208       
2006-01-03 00:01:08.654  0.85213       
2006-01-03 00:01:08.859  0.85212       
2006-01-03 00:01:11.472  0.85215       
2006-01-03 00:01:12.002  0.85218  
...                          ...  
2020-03-15 23:59:57.150  0.85178  
2020-03-15 23:59:57.300  0.85179  
2020-03-15 23:59:58.233  0.85179  
2020-03-15 23:59:58.366  0.85178  
2020-03-15 23:59:58.595  0.85179
```

When I run the loop outside of the function, the printed values appear as expected.

I am new to programming and would really appreciate some advice/help.
Thanks!

**I'm using Python 3.7.9 and NumPy 1.19.1**

Comment: This code doesn't raise any exceptions for me (Python 3.7.1): `next(np.nditer(np.array([2,4,5])) > 0`. "'>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'int'" looks extremely weird - `numpy.ndarray` can very much be compared to an integer, and the result will be an array of booleans

Comment: @ForceBru, ...though since that array will always be treated as a truthy value when non-empty (`bool([0])` being `True`, f/e), using it in an `if` seems unlikely to be what someone wanted.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, not really: the error should've been `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`, because it's ambiguous whether `np.array([True, False])` is truthy or not. But the `TypeError` in the post doesn't make any sense to me...

Comment: Ahh -- numpy going beyond regular Python list semantics is a useful thing to know; ty. :)

Comment: @Greg, please [edit] the question to specify the exact versions of Python and of numpy.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I edited the question to include Python and NumPy version

Comment: `Data` is a string, `Results = RunBacktest(Gran, Period, ZMinMax, upperbound, lowerbound, UpperExit, LowerExit, Data)` sends the string to the argument `Array`, you can't compare `np.dtype('<U*')` with `int`,

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) Using a debugger to step through your program and see what the variables actually contain can be _very_ enlightening.